# Is there a service that can use google api to monitor changes in google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am very new to JavaScript and Google app script. I want to monitor changes in a sheet. And if there is an edit, I want a script function to run. Triggers are not an option here to use because they have small quota limit. So I can not use onEdit or time driven triggers to call my function. I need some service to use Google API to monitor changes in google sheet and then trigger the function. Is it possible? Can someone please help me with this? 
Thank You :)

Comment: As in Webhooks no, AFAIK only periocally checks, and those also have a limit.

Comment: @Kriggs Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What is the peridiocity you need?

Comment: @Kriggs actually i want to monitor the sheet continuously at all times. i was thinking of deploying the service on cloud server (if it is possible) that can monitor google sheet at all times for changes. So periodicity is going to be very high. it should check for changes after every second.

Comment: Every few seconds? No, not possible, I would use a combination of onEdit and newTrigger, that reaches your service with URLFetch, the newTrigger would fire in XX seconds after the last edit, and no more than 1 trigger would be active at the same time, so you won't reach a cap. I assume you have quite the coding knowledge, it's quite a task to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without triggers/onEdit and without polling the spreadsheet api. Beware this is hacky but it has the advantage of not using apps script quotas or spreadsheet api quotas to detect changes
1) in the spreadsheet enable email notifications whenever the spreadsheet changes.
2) using gmail filters send those notification emails to a label.
3) using the gmail api (has larger quotas) look for that email by finding emails with That label.
note that this does avoid quota issues with spreadsheets but i really think its much better to just use the regular triggers/onEdit/onChange and just live with the 1minute delay. Quotas will not be exhausted if you simply detect change and call urlfetch.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it does not solve the issue. I need an external service to monitor the sheet and I need to make real time workflows. So I can't bear with 1 minute delay and still the quota limit is there.

Comment: the solution proposed here completely avoids the 1minute delay and the quotas issue. See here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota which is the only quota you will have to deal with (tldr: 250 calls per second and a billion calls daily). Reading the spreadsheet on each change will require much less api calls as you will only do them when the sheet actually changes. Its imposible to make this more effcient with the restrictions you are giving.